# How to disable Hotjar recording when consent changes?

Tags: hotjar

I have a single-page application that uses Hotjar.  I load the Hotjar javascript as part of the bootstrapper page's scripts:

```
<script>
    (function(h,o,t,j,a,r){
        h.hj=h.hj||function(){(h.hj.q=h.hj.q||[]).push(arguments)};
        h._hjSettings={hjid:1234567,hjsv:6};
        a=o.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        r=o.createElement('script');r.async=1;
        r.src=t+h._hjSettings.hjid+j+h._hjSettings.hjsv;
        a.appendChild(r);
    })(window,document,'https://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-','.js?sv=');
</script>
```

This works fine and I can see recordings of user activity in my Hotjar account.

What I was expecting was some kind of mechanism to stop recording sessions when they withdraw consent.  Google Tag Manager supports this, as described at https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/security/guides/consent#implementation_example (note, select the `Tag Manager` tab, not `gtag.js` tab).

I cannot find any documentation on Hotjar's website that covers how users can change their consent in a similar way to how Google's consent works.

https://www.hotjar.com/privacy/ mentions consent ("We have built the necessary controls around anonymity and consent...") but in the compliance resources page (https://help.hotjar.com/hc/en-us/sections/360007812474-Compliance) there is no mention of consent whatsoever!

I recognise that I could dynamically load the Hotjar script only once I have confirmed that consent has been provided, but I can't see an elegant way in a single-page application to stop recording if they withdraw consent after the SPA has loaded.

Once the Hotjar script has loaded I can see an `hj` object in the page which seems to have a fairly rich set of methods and properties.  I cannot find these methods or properties documented anywhere.

Is there a way to use the `hj` object to stop recording dynamically?